# How can I use two HDD as one on Debian?

Tags: partition, lvm

I have installed Debian on my server with a 250GB HDD. Now I have bought another HDD that is 2TB large, but I don't know how I could use that 2TB with my webhosting solution.

I heard about LVM, but can I use it after I installed Debian, or is it better to copy everything and reinstall my Linux?

Comment: May be If I mount the new HDD and change the server routing to HDD2 is that a solution?

Comment: That fixes your most immediate problem of using the 2TB for web hosting. You may run into issues, though, if you want to add a third drive to the mix. For your question, though, you can see if Debian installs on LVM by default (like RHEL does, no idea on Debian) by checking for volume groups in the output of `vgs`. Even if it doesn't, reinstallation would be overkill, just create logical volumes off the larger drive now so that migration and expansion is easier down the road without having to take the website down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the size differences I would not bother to combine the 250Gb drive with the new 2TB drive. Just leave the system on the 250Gb drive and use the 2GB drive as a data partition for your webhosting.

You should just partition the 2TB drive and make new filesystem on the new partition. Then mount that new partition and move the webhosting data there, after which you have to configure your webserver to take the data from the new location.